# JavaScript String Encryption

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I would like to encrypt one line of text using the following encryption scheme.

This is the sample input. First, the spaces are removed from the text.

```
haveaniceday
```

Then, returns the length of a string `(L = 12)`. Next, characters are written into a grid, whose rows and columns have the following constraints:

The length of a string will return the square root of `L` is between `3` and `4`. Thus, rewritten with 3 rows and 4 columns:

```
have
anic
eday
```

Finally, the encoded message is obtained by displaying the characters in a column, inserting a space, and then displaying the next column and inserting a space, and so on.

For example, the encoded message for the above rectangle is:

```
hae and via ecy
```

In my code snippets, the grid `["have", "anic", "eday"]` already created, but I have no idea how to achieve the next stage.

```js
const s = "haveaniceday";
let result = encryption(s);

function encryption(s) {

  let sqr = Math.sqrt(s.length),
    col = Math.ceil(sqr),
    row = Math.floor(sqr);

  let chunks = chunkSubstr(s, col);
  // => ["have", "anic", "eday"]
  console.log(chunks);

  for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    // do some magic here...      
    // expected output: "hae and via ecy"
  }

}


function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
  }

  return chunks
}
```

Comment: Stop treating programming as magic: now you need to fetch the first character from first "word", then first character from the second "word", ..., then second character from the first "word", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get each character in chunks by looping the count of col.

```js
const s = "haveaniceday";
let result = encryption(s);

function encryption(s) {

  let sqr = Math.sqrt(s.length),
    col = Math.ceil(sqr),
    row = Math.floor(sqr);

  let chunks = chunkSubstr(s, col);
  // => ["have", "anic", "eday"]
  console.log(chunks);

  let output = '';
  for (var i=0; i<col; i++) {
    chunks.forEach((e) => {
      if (e[i]) {
        output += e[i];
      }
    });
    output += ' ';
  }
  console.log(output);

}


function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
  }

  return chunks
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your Array `["have" "anic" "eday"]` in an other Array, the length of your strings. For each three members of the original Array, you'll map all its characters into the new Array.

```js
const original = ["have", "anic", "eday"];
const output = original.reduce((out, word) => {
 word.split("") // break into characters[]
  .forEach((char, i) =>
    out[i] += char // append this char to the corresponding string of `out`
  );
 return out;
}, new Array(original[0].length).fill('')) // ['', '', '', '']
console.log(output.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

easy => array.joint(' ') in the end, and a double loop

```js
const s = "haveaniceday";
let result = encryption(s);

console.log ('result =', result );

function encryption(s) {

  let
    sqr = Math.sqrt(s.length),
    col = Math.ceil(sqr),
    row = Math.floor(sqr)
    ;

  let chunks = chunkSubstr(s, col);
  // => ["have", "anic", "eday"]

  let Respons = [];
  
  for (let i=0, iMax=chunks[0].length; i<iMax; i++ ) {

    Respons[i] = '';
    for (let txt of chunks ) {
      Respons[i] += txt.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return Respons.join(' ');
}


function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const
    numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size),
    chunks    = new Array(numChunks)
    ;

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
  }
    return chunks
}
```

Comment: They want `"hae and via ecy"` not `"have anic eday"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    const s = "haveaniceday";
    let result = encryption(s);

    function encryption(s) {

      let sqr = Math.sqrt(s.length),
        col = Math.ceil(sqr),
        row = Math.floor(sqr);

      let chunks = chunkSubstr(s, col);
      // => ["have", "anic", "eday"]
      console.log(chunks);
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        // do some magic here...      
        // expected output: "hae and via ecy"

         var split =  Array.from(chunks[i]);
         for (var s = 0; s < split.length; s++) {

            var previousValue = '';
            if(result[s])
             { previousValue = result[s];}

            result[s]=previousValue + split[s];
    }


      }

console.log(result);

    }


    function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
      const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
      const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

      for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
        chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
      }

      return chunks
    }
```